# "Group" model in Struct class throwing undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, struct

I have a Job class that is being created with a Struct. I recently added a ActiveRecord model named `Group` and I need to reset the counters on this `Group` model from within the `perform` method of this class like so:

```
module Jobs
  class ProcessV1 < Struct.new(:payload, :reporting_ip)

    def perform
      Group.reset_counters 1, :computers
    end

  end
end
```

This however is throwing an error of:

```
undefined method "reset_counters" for Etc::Group:Class
```

In some quick googling I've learned that apparently `Group` is a subclass of Etc which is related to Struct somehow. Is there a way around this without renaming my `Group` model?

#### My first attempt

I tried the following to further specify the models location

```
ApplicationName::Application::Group
```

which gets rid of my Etc::Group error but then I get:

```
warning: toplevel constant Group referenced by ApplicationName::Application::Group
```

Comment: If you actually want the toplevel Group constant, try `::Group`

Comment: So ::Group worked! How is that different from ApplicationName::Application::Group though?

Comment: `::Group` is the toplevel constant, `ApplicationName::Application::Group` would be a constant defined under `ApplicationName::Application`.

Comment: Chris if you'll submit your comment as an answer please.

Comment: Added. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want the toplevel Group constant, try `::Group`. That explicitly tells Ruby that you want the top-level constant, rather than it walking up the module tree to find a `Group` constant.